# Octave console buffering output

Tags: command-line-interface, octave, read-eval-print-loop

I am having trouble debugging because Octave (I am using 4.0.0) is not displaying output to the console immediately.  I see output from the **disp** command only after long running commands located **after** the disp command finish executing.

Usually this some kind of line buffering problem. Is anyone else experiencing this? Is there a workaround?

I have all of the gui stuff switched off; I am running octave like so:

```
octave -q --no-gui --norc
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. There are various options for paging, but **more off** was sufficient for me.

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Paging-Screen-Output.html